# Do not give me Edit credits I do not deserve

Tags: feature-request, edits

When I do a Tag Edit, and one of the Tags is a synonym of a master Tag, the system automatically changes that Tag to match the master, and makes it look like I did the change. [Here is an example (Edit 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18335830/revisions). Another case is when I do an edit and the trailing period/dot of the Question title gets automatically removed.

There are maybe other examples of such automated editing, but I prefer a world that is free of deception, especially if it can be avoided.

Comment: You mean you only removed the [incoming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/incoming) tag in there?

Comment: Yeah, that is all I did.

Comment: Well, the edits do need to be made. What if the system appended something like "automatic edits applied" to the end of the edit reason?

Comment: @animuson I think extra revision is better, made by Community user with helpful summary.

Comment: @animuson I prefer what Shadow Wizard suggests.