# When salutations are automatically removed, should a new revision be made to show this?

Tags: discussion, edits, quality-filter

When I edit a question, site scripts can automatically apply edits which are deemed as required in addition to my edit.
The script's edits are stored in the edit history under my name inline with my edit.

### Example

See edit #7 here, I only edited out the "naval-gazing" tag, but the other edits in #7 are from site scripts automatically applying other edits on top of mine:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/44145/revisions

### Problems

**A)**
This is potentially confusing to users who are not aware site scripts can add additional edits to theirs - the human might start trying to roll back or re-edit thinking they did something wrong.

**B)**
It's a little "intrusive" in that it's *my* edit, and also I might actually disagree with the auto edits.
As a human, I can determine things which scripts cannot, and while the scripts are pretty well sorted, the text which they removed from the example I linked to was valid text and should have remained in this case - given this is Meta, and because it suited the context to the question.

I do not want the edits I do not agree with to be in my name.

**C)**
If a human performs an edit and site scripts add additional edits, and either:

1. Human edit was wrong, site scripts edit was correct
2. Site scripts edit was wrong, human edit was correct

In either case, one cannot separately roll back the incorrect edit, and if the wrong edit is bad enough where roll back is imperative, we lose a good edit.

So the site's auto editing scripts should be separate to ours, so they can be rolled back separately if needed.

---

I've asked as a discussion rather than proposal, as I don't know the entire scenario with the site scripts auto editing etc.
Also, I don't know how frequent an issue this might be.

Since this actions are not performed by Community User and is instead just some site scripts, perhaps such auto operations *should* be pushed to Community User in some way so we *can* have separate edit history.

Comment: I also don't really want someone else's edits masquerading as mine - and especially not some machine which cannot feel love or compassion, or smell a rose (wait, I'm not really that insecure..)

Comment: It's not the community user. There is a special code that simply removes things like "thanks" and as it turns out also "Dearly Beloved" from the post once it's being submitted. (after looking into it, anything starting with  "dear" will be removed automagically)

Comment: Here is the official annoucement of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/152859

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ah thanks. I suppose that explains why there is no separate edit history.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do not give me Edit credits I do not deserve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233758/do-not-give-me-edit-credits-i-do-not-deserve)